# Flat file database for use between mobile and desktop

Tags: .net, database, file, nosql

I'm beginning to work on an application that would need data records to be synced between a windows desktop application and a mobile device. I do not want to use a "cloud" database to do this. I'd like to enable the user to use dropbox, onedrive, etc to facilitate the sync.

The idea is simply this: a user creates a new record via the desktop application, the database is uploaded via dropbox, the mobile app is then able to pull this new record in to the mobile app and display the data to the user. The user would also be able to create a record in the mobile app and it needs to find its way back to the desktop app without issues. I do not expect the user to be using both apps at the same time.

I'm not looking for a cloud database, or anything that runs locally as a service. I'd like to not use a single file db like SQLite or others due to the file being in use, corruption, etc when trying to sync. I've written some C# tests to see what it would be like to create each record as an individual file with "tables" essentially being represented as folders. It's slow as you would expect, but works well. I'm not expecting lots of records. Maybe a few per day, but I know as this accumulates over the years, the processing time of reading the files could become a problem.

Is there any .NET library that's already doing something like this, or have any of you done anything like this? I've found several document style databases, but again, they way they function, I'm concerned about syncing a single file or two. I want the software to not lock the file(s) unless they are being written to.

Or, maybe I'm thinking about this problem all wrong. I'm totally open to suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: Looking for about the same thing. Currently I'm experimenting with nosql-like solution: class collection is mapped to folder, every class instance maps to the single json file. I use ServiceStack's library for (de)serializing classes from/to json. File is updated on any member change. To catch "remote" changes made by other users I'm using FileSystemWatcher. For a while not sure how smooth it will work if root directory is synchronized thru cloud service (Sharepoint folder mapped to local one in my case); and what will happen if multiple users will start edit records (classes) simultaneously.

Comment: @Dmitry that's essentially what I was toying with in my tests. It works well, but I wonder what it'll look like 5 years down the road and loading 50K files at startup. Overall, it's a really straight forward solution to the problem, but I'm concerned about load times as the data set gets bigger.

Comment: I also tackled this problem when writing a note-taking application, the notes I took at work, I wanted to appear at home, and vice-versa.  My app lets you create hundreds of notes, each note is a row in a SQLite db.  However each note is also written to a GDrive folder.  The tricky part is avoiding collisions, so each note when changed is written with a timestamp as part of the filename.  So as far as Google is concerned, its a new file.  Gdrive can lock it, I dont care, my copy is in the local DB.  I watch for changes in the folder, use the timestamp to get the latest, and update the DB.